# Preforming enter click, cefsharp

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am trying to perform enter click in browser for html element. In IE default web browser control the code be something like this:

```
HtmlElement htmlel = GoogleWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("lst-ib");
htmlel.SetAttribute("value", companyTextBox.Text);
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

I am interested in Cef sharp alternative. The root problem is that javascript function for click on input html element won't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42969621/4583726 for an example you can adapt to your own needs.